# Mesh and armature not connected

Tags: mesh, armature

I created a a blender figure, with mesh and armature, and I followed the instructions to connect the mesh with the armature:

1. Select the mesh
2. Shift+Select the armature
3. Ctrl + P
4. Set parent to armature deform with automatic weights

However, in pose mode the bones can move, but the mesh will not move along.

Could you point me the on right direction to address this issue?

[image]

[image: Bone not moving flesh]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of vertices overlaying, you need to select your mesh, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* (or <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* since last versions) with a *Merge Distance* (on the bottom of the *Tools* panel) of 0.01.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed the doubles with merge distance of 0.01, and then set parent to armature with automatic weights. It worked perfectly